# How could I create indexes in postgres using jsonb?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table in my database as follows

my_table:jsonb

```json
[ {
  "name" : "world map",
  "type" : "activated",
  "map" : [ {
    "displayOrder" : 0,
    "value" : 123
  }, {
    "displayOrder" : 1,
    "value" : 456
  }, {
    "displayOrder" : 2,
    "value" : 789
  } ]
}, {
  "name" : "regional map",
  "type" : "disabled"
} ]
```

I would like to create indices for the `name`, `type` and `displayOrder` fields, which would be the best way?

Comment: You have nested arrays there. You can't directly create indexes on keys inside arrays. The type of index depends completely on the queries you are going to run. So without showing us how your queries look like, we can't give you an answer on what type of index to create.

Comment: The query would be more or less like this.

```
select * from my_table,
  jsonb_to_recordset(my_table.column_jsonb) as c(name text, type text,map jsonb),
  jsonb_to_recordset(c.map) as m(name text, "displayOrder" int)
where type = 'activated'
AND map @> '{ name: 'world map' }'::jsonb
group by c.name, m."displayOrder"
order by m."displayOrder" ASC;
```

Comment: Please update your question with relevant information, not just add it to the comments. thanks